# Alignment of text of a column in a table using jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jspdf

I exported html table into pdf using jspdf.I am trying to format the table. I was able to adjust the margins. I want to align few columns of table to right and few to left. In the table I want first column to be aligned to left and last column to be aligned to right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>

{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/js/libs/polyfill.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/jspdf.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/js/libs/deflate.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/js/libs/adler32cs.js/adler32cs.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/js/libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/js/libs/Blob.js/Blob.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.cell.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js")}}
{{ HTML::script("js/jspdf/js/basic-test.js")}}

</head>
 <body>
     <div id="tblSaveAsPdf" class="table-details margin-top-small collapse" style="display: none; margin-top: -10em;">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover bootstrap-datatable datatable dataTable table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr role="row"> <%--class="headerRow"--%>
                                <th role="columnheader" class="col-lg-2">Account</th>
                                <th role="columnheader" class="col-lg-3">Description</th>
                                <th role="columnheader" class="col-lg-3">Journal Entry#</th>
                                <th role="columnheader" class="col-lg-2">Debit</th>
                                <th role="columnheader" class="col-lg-2">Credit</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                         <tfoot>
                            <tr role="row">
                                <td style="text-align: center">
                                    <span>TOTAL</span>
                                </td>     
                                <td></td>  
                                <td></td>                                                        
                                <td  style="text-align: right">
                                    <span data-bind="text: pp_formattedDebitTotal"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td   style="text-align: right">
                                    <span data-bind="text: pp_formattedCreditTotal"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                        <tbody  data-bind="foreach: pp_voidCheckGLSummarys">
                            <tr >
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: pp_account"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td >
                                    <span data-bind="text: pp_accountName"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: pp_entry"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: pp_amountDebit"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: pp_amountCredit"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            </div>
                        </tbody>  
      <div>
     <button onclick="demoFromHTML()" class="button">SAvePDF</button></p></div></div>
     </div>
```

Here is javascript file

```
       <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
       demoFromHTML();
      });

     function demoFromHTML() {
     var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter')
     , source = $('#tblSaveAsPdf')[0]
     ,  specialElementHandlers = {
     '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
      return true
       }
      }

     margins = {
      top: 80,
      bottom: 60,
      left: 40,
      width: 522
      };

  pdf.fromHTML(
     source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
     , margins.left // x coord
     , margins.top // y coord
     , {
     'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
     , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
     },
    function (dispose) {   
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
      },
    margins

     )
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok the solution is split your table in different tables by columns and align it with jspdf.plugin.htmltable.js. hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is modify the jspdf.plugin.htmltable.js to swith cell.align. And add align in the cells of html table.

```
switch (options.align || cell.align) {
     case '-webkit-right':
     case 'right':
       if (!(txt instanceof Array)) {
           txt = [txt];
       }
       for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
         var textSize = this.getStringUnitWidth(txt[i]) * this.internal.getFontSize();
         this.text(txt[i], cursor.x + cell_widths[x] - textSize - padding, cursor.y + this.internal.getLineHeight()*(i+1));
        }
   break;
```